# python - loop through file and delete rows with certain Ip addresses

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python, but I started a project of importing a csv file and looping through the file while deleting lines that has non routable IP addresses in them.  This is an example of the csv file:

```
md5                                 domain      ip
0001184ebc4a4c8c641074e7d597a373    twitter.com  104.244.42.1
```

This is the code I compiled but it isn't working:

```
with open('orig_file', 'rb') as f, open('new_file', 'wb') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g)
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        if row in range('192.168.1.0/24'):
            del row[]
```

I'm confident that if I can get the line with the asterisk work I can figure our the rest.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What line with asterisk?

Comment: `range('192.168.1.0/24')` seriously?

Comment: I am aware that range takes an int(start:stop:interval) but wasn't quite sure on if this could handle an IP address.  I did a few web searches and seen a few examples and gave those a try.

Answer (score 1):

`range()` doesn't handle IP addresses, it's only for numerical ranges:

```
range(stop) -> range object
range(start, stop[, step]) -> range object

Return an object that produces a sequence of integers from start (inclusive)
to stop (exclusive) by step.  range(i, j) produces i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1.
start defaults to 0, and stop is omitted!  range(4) produces 0, 1, 2, 3.
These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
```

The `ipaddress` module in Python 3 (can be installed in Python 2 with `pip install ipaddress`) can do exactly what you want:

```
In [7]: import ipaddress

In [8]: ipaddress.ip_address('1.2.3.4') in ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')
Out[8]: False

In [9]: ipaddress.ip_address('192.168.1.1') in ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24')
Out[9]: True
```

Something like this should work:

```
import ipaddress

with open('orig_file', 'rb') as f, open('new_file', 'wb') as g:
    writer = csv.writer(g)

    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ip = ipaddress.ip_address(row[0])

        if ip in ipaddress.ip_network('192.168.1.0/24'):
            continue

        writer.write(row)
```